# Deploy Azure VPN gateway to existing vnet without affecting existing subnets

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, gateway, azure-rm-template, azure-virtual-network

I am attempting to deploy a new Azure Virtual Network Gateway to an existing VNET that includes several subnets. I am configuring this in a test environment first with a dummy subnet. I am using ARM to create a .json template and parameters file, which I am deploying via Jenkins. Currently the template attempts to redeploy the whole VNET when it deploys the Virtual Network Gateway. I do not want it to do this. I want it to deploy the Virtual Network Gateway to the existing VNET. Please see below for how I am coding the VNET in the template.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
    "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
      "addressSpace": {
        "addressPrefixes": [
          "[parameters('azureVNetAddressPrefix')]"
        ]
      },
      "subnets": [
        {
          "name": "GatewaySubnet",
          "properties": {
            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('gatewaySubnetPrefix')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am getting the following error in Jenkins when deploying this template:

```
"code": "InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted",

"message": "Subnet testing-subnet is in use by /subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/networks-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/dev-jmp-d31653/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1 and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet."
```

I've looked at the Microsoft knowledgebase but I've struggled to find an explanation of how I can do this, or whether it's even possible. Ideally, I'd like to avoid listing all of the subnets in the vnet, as this is a template I want to apply to different vnets with different subnets.

Can anyone provide answers or advice? Thanks.

Comment: Is it an option to use PowerShell to add the gateway?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-tutorial-create-gateway-powershell

Comment: It is a potential option but I would much rather use ARM if possible. If I can't find an acceptable ARM solution then I'll attempt a PowerShell solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be supported very well in ARM. This is because a VNET is a resource and a subnet is a property of that resource. When an ARM template is deployed, any resources not mentioned are ignored (in iterative mode, at least).

However, properties of existing resources that are mentioned MUST BE SPECIFIED. This is because Azure tries to implement the resource as specified in the template. If a property is different, it will alter it. If a property is absent, it will REMOVE it.

Potential solutions:

1. Have multiple templates for each of your vnets. When you make a change, you update the whole vnet. This requires you to track several templates and is not ideal for infrastructure as code, but is a simple solution.
2. Use a powershell solution instead:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-tutorial-create-gateway-powershell. I haven't tried this myself as I've been told to use ARM by my superiors, but it has been suggested on several forums as an alternative.

3. You could also attempt to use a copyloop as per this guidance, but this has limited utility and I haven't yet verified if you can use a name array rather than a number array:

https://pkm-technology.com/azure-vnet-json/

4. Update your subnets as part of a separate template. This requires you to also update your master vnet template as well, otherwise your new subnets will be removed if you ever redeploy the master vnet template. Also, you can only add subnets in this way. It doesn't help if you want to do something else, such as deploy a VPN gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The following ARM template will add a subnet to a virtual network with existing subnets and will not disturb the existing subnets.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "VNet1"
    },
    "gatewaySubnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.2.0/24"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '/GatewaySubnet')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('gatewaySubnetPrefix')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to add a subnet to a vnet in this case. I'm trying to deploy a virtual network gateway without disturbing existing subnets.